# array_to_json returns number instead of string for bigint

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I'm using Postgres' (9.3.13) `array_to_json` function to serialize a bigint `id` field into a JSON array.

During the execution of some unit and acceptance test I realized that the result of `array_to_json` is an array of numbers instead of an array of strings, which I expected.

My problem is that the [largest safe integer in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) is:
25^3 - 1 (9007199254740991),

whereas the [largest bignum in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html) is:
9223372036854775807

wouldn't that lead to unsafe representation of numbers greater than `25^3 - 1` in Javascript? Is that really the desired behavior of Postgres' json serialization? And if yes, how can I make `array_to_json` return an array of strings instead of numbers?

Comment: The JSON spec actually does not contain any constraint about how large a number can be in it (it is *based* on a JavaScript spec, but became independent from it -- aka. ECMA-404 The JSON Data Interchange Standard -- *f.ex. JSON cannot represent NaN and Infinity, but JavaScript can*). In JSON you can represent numbers in any size with any precision: it is up the host language & the parser to understand it correctly.

Comment: For the record, JavaScript too *can* understand numbers above `25^3-1` but will (could) apply some rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your input array into a text array:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array[1,2,3]::TEXT[]);
-- returns ["1","2","3"]
```